# How can you execute a Node.js script via a cron job?

Tags: node.js, cron

Quite simply, I have node script that I want to execute once a month.

```
30 6 1 * * node /home/steve/example/script.js
```

But this doesn't work, presumably because of path or the shell the command is being ran under. I've tried the following means of executing node via cron (tested with -v):

```
steve@atom:~$ node -v
v0.4.2

steve@atom:~$ sh node -v
sh: Can't open node

steve@atom:~$ bash node -v
/usr/local/bin/node: /usr/local/bin/node: cannot execute binary file

steve@atom:~$ /usr/local/bin/node -v
v0.4.2

steve@atom:~$ sh /usr/local/bin/node -v
/usr/local/bin/node: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

steve@atom:~$ bash /usr/local/bin/node -v
/usr/local/bin/node: /usr/local/bin/node: cannot execute binary file
```

I've ran out of ideas to try, any advice?

Comment: Read this https://github.com/wahengchang/nodejs-cron-job-must-know ('nodejs-cron-job-must-know' section). It is needed to navigate to the directory where script is located using `cd` command. I tried maybe everything but only after this it started to work.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

just provide the full path to node `/usr/local/bin/node` in your cron job like:

```
30 6 1 * * /usr/local/bin/node /home/steve/example/script.js
```

Comment: It turned out to be a couple of problems, the full path as you said fixed the cron, but relative paths in the script were also a issue.

Comment: @Steve how did you fix the relative path issues?

Comment: @Steve I'm using the config module (e.g. require('config').DB) and when running via crontab, the config variables are not populated.

Comment: WARNING! If you were using nvm or n to manage your node installs - putting `/usr/local/bin/node` - may not work! In order to obtain the actual path to node, use `which node` - then put that path before your script.
E.G. I am using node 0.10.32 from nvm, so my path to node is: `/home/username/.nvm/v0.10.32/bin/node`

Comment: @YemSalat It is better to declare that in a node version indepentdent way: # doc Required to enable node/nvm for a cronjob ()
# doc  cron uses by default a short PATH = /usr/bin:/bin and does not execute /root/.bashrc (equal to /root/.bashrc)
# doc  nvm (node version manager) does not configure itself in a crontab job (that is only done for interactive shells in my /root/.bashrc).
    export NVM_DIR="/root/.nvm"
    [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm

Comment: is this problem just node-specific or do I always need to add the path to the program?

Comment: I'm still getting module not found , but I can run it well when I cd into it

Comment: Thanks! [Here's an example](https://gist.github.com/simov/cdbebe2d65644279db1323042fcf7624) if you want to integrate nvm too

Answer (score 63):

These answers here saying using absolute path will all cause major problems for running a larger node app!

**Real Complete Solution**

**Find Node Path**

```
which node
```

**Edit Cron Jobs**

```
crontab -e
```

**Set your Change Cron Job to CD into the destination folder, call Node Path by it's full path and run script**

```
*/2 * * * * cd /home/destination/path && /bin/node index.js
```

This will then allow you to run a full NodeJS application without all the errors like how using an absolute path for your index.js file.

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer, I tried the most voted solution but my script didn't work, then I tried other solutions, lig node-cron, but your solution works, is simple and easy to understand!

Comment: This was the perfect answer for me too, thank you!

Comment: This one actually works for me as well.  Thanks man.

Comment: This should be marked as answer. Thanks mate!

Comment: This was killing me. Thank you! Also a note to people after. For me the confusion was that Cron on Ubuntu is operating as root, even if you aren't editing it as such. Make sure your paths are absolute from the root, not just from your profile.

Comment: This solution works fine! Solved the problem for me. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. This answer is not just work but showing how to find where node is, and how to edit crontab. Very well.

Answer (score 30):

Additionally, just put `#!/usr/local/bin/node` at the top of the script you want to execute. Then it will automatically know to execute the script with node. Make sure the file is executable as well.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env node` is a little more future proof as `env` will point to wherever your `node` is installed.

Answer (score 13):

You can also specify paths to binary files on top of your user crontab like:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin

* * * * * cd your/path && node foo.js
* * * * * cd your/path && npm run bar
```

Comment: perfect! That's what I wanted!

Answer (score 8):

in my laptop using Linux mint the given path not working so i used this to get a work around.

`$ which node`

`$ /usr/bin/node`
this worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

This also works for user-level cron jobs

```
 */2 * * * * cd /home/destination/path && $(which node) index.js
```

Comment: using `$(which node)` works great if you're using a version manager like NVM.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if changing your relative paths in your script to absolute paths is a good idea
(what happens when your file system changes or you deploy in another environment?)

You could try wrapping it in a shell script, setting some environment variables in the crontab execution. (specifically `PATH` & `NODE_PATH` for starters)

Try my suggestion for this similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27823675/608269

Answer (score 4):

## NVM users:

Save the following script (say, cronjob.env.sh) anywhere at your PATH (let's say: $HOME/bin). Remember to make it executable (chmod +x). Replace 'username' with your user name as well:

```
#!/bin/bash
export NVM_DIR="/home/username/.nvm"   #replace "username" with your user name
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

Edit cronjob:

```
crontab -e
```

Insert/edit your job:

```
0 0 * * * (. ~/bin/cronjob.env.sh; ~/bin/my-script-with-node-cmd.sh)
```

Calling node command (instead of some shell script), like the below job, works as well:

```
*/1 * * * * (. ~/bin/cronjob.env.sh; node ~/index.js)
```

## PM2 users:

A different approach is using `pm2`, with `--cron` option, which accepts cron patterns (inside quotation marks):

```
pm2 start index.js --no-autorestart --cron "0 0 * * *"
```

`--no-autorestart` is for one-time scripts (otherwise, it will be restarted every time it is completed).

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute paths for the node alias and the file to be run.

**Edit Cron Jobs**

```
crontab -e
```

**Entry to Run Our Node File**

This will run every minute.

```
*/1 * * * * * /bin/node /public/test.js
```

Full Tutorial
https://askmacgyver.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-run-node-scripts-from-a-cron-job

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the `nvm` functionality and allow your code to get an updated node version without needing to change the cron job info, put your job in a shell script that first sets up `nvm`, switches to proper `node` version, then runs the actual job. Here is an example for a project called `invoicing` that includes a `cron` script in its `package.json`.

File `invoicing.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/produser/invoicing
export NVM_DIR="/home/produser/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
npm run cron
```

Then set this up as the command in your cron job listing:

```
0 16 1 * * produser /home/produser/invoicing/invoicing.sh
```

Now, if you change the node version in your project and update your `.nvmrc` with the proper version number and pull the new code onto the server, the next time the cron job runs it will run with version of node specified. Note that you must also make sure the server has the required node version.

Answer (score 0):

There is a kind of simpler solution to this.
While some may suggest using the absolute path for the node exec inside cron file, you may just add a symlink to it instead - it leads to shorter, cleaner commands in the cron file.

1. Get the path for the node exec:

> which node

This path may differ, depending on the installation method that was used for node. For example, /root/n/bin/node if you used n node version manager.

2. Copy the result, then create a symlink:

> ln -s copiedPathFromStepAbove /usr/bin/node

Usually /usr/bin/node should be in path used for the crons.
If it still doesn't work, you can check the actual PATH used for crons by adding a temporary cron job (will exec every minute, make sure you remove it afterwards):

> crontab -e

Add:

```
* * * * * echo $PATH >> /root/debug.log
```

Wait until the debug.log file shows up then check the contents for the path.