# How to set cron job correct path to run a node.js script?

Tags: node.js, unix, cron, cron-task

I'm trying to automate a Node.js file to run on schedule.
But I can't get it to work.

I'm using **root** user.

This is the path to get to the file location from login:
`nodejs_projects/amazon_search_v2`

Here is pwd output from the login location:

```
root@project:~# pwd
/root
```

And this is the script i'm adding in **crontab** :

```
0 4,12,20 * * * node nodejs_projects/amazon_search_v2/searchItemsApi.js  >/dev/null 2>&1
```

What am i'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me:

`* 0,8,16 * * * cd ~/nodejs_projects/amazon_search_v2/ && /usr/bin/node searchItemsApi.js >/dev/null 2>&1`

As described here:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849402/how-can-you-execute-a-node-js-script-via-a-cron-job/5849463)

In Curtis Xiao answer.
Using `which node` to find the node executable path and `cd` to get into the file folder and prevent relative path issues.

Answer (score 0):

- You have to provide a full path to node `/usr/local/bin/node` like this.

`0 4,12,20 * * * /usr/local/bin/node nodejs_projects/amazon_search_v2/searchItemsApi.js  >/dev/null 2>&1`

- Better way is to use **node-cron** library.

```
const cron = require('node-cron');
 
cron.schedule('0 4,12,20 * * *', function(){
  // task goes here
});
```

- For more detail, please refer [this example](https://github.com/wahengchang/nodejs-cron-job-must-know).

Comment: Thanks, but I had memory issues using node-cron so i want to try a regular cron job to see if that is the issue.